# Adding css from jquery to elements with specified class name and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to set css for some elements from my page with `jQuery`.
I can't modify `html` code.
I need to set `css` for the `span` element.
I have more spans with the same `class name` but with another text on it.
I have these text on the span: Read More or Load More.
I need to add css only with the buttons with Read More.

This is the `html`:

```
<div class="loop-entry-content clr">
    <header>
        <h2 class="loop-entry-title entry-title">
            <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/organization-trapped-inside-legacy-box/">Is Your Organization Trapped Inside the ...</a>
        </h2>
    </header>

    <div class="loop-entry-excerpt entry clr">
        In my first job out of college, I worked as a Cobol programmer updating the computer ...<br>
        <span class="home_readmore"><a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/organization-trapped-inside-legacy-box/">Read more</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
 $('#readMore_button').addClass('home_readmore_button');

 $("span:contains('Read More')").parent().addClass("home_readmore_button");
```

The first modifies the all elements with the same class. The second it does nothing. Thanks!

Comment: do you want to add <span class="home_readmore"> css to this span ?

Comment: As mentioned on the jQuery website here: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/, the ':contains' selector is case sensitive. Change your 'Read More' to 'Read more' and it'll work (the second case)

Comment: the first is not modifying all elements but should be only 1 element as it is using id selector, id should be unique (only 1), if not then your HTML is flawed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the text of each span of your class and add your css rule if necessaire

```
$("span.className").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text.toLowerCase() == 'read more'){
         $(this).addClass("home_readmore_button");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The docs for [:selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) state:

> text: A string of text to look for. It's **case sensitive**.

So you need to have:

```
$("span:contains('Read more')").parent().addClass("home_readmore_button");
```

```js
$("span:contains('Read more')").parent().addClass("home_readmore_button");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loop-entry-content clr">
        <header>
         <h2 class="loop-entry-title entry-title">
          <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/organization-trapped-inside-legacy-box/">Is Your Organization Trapped Inside the ...</a>
          </h2>
        </header>

    <div class="loop-entry-excerpt entry clr">
              In my first job out of college, I worked as a Cobol programmer updating the computer ...<br>
         <span class="home_readmore"><a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/organization-trapped-inside-legacy-box/">Read more</a></span>
     </div>
 </div>
```